# Python - How to change a lambda function to partial function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, partial-application

The lambda function is:

```
lambda x: x.split('=')
```

the partial function would look something like:

```
str.split('=')
```

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: edited @NilsWerner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a function that does partial functions

```
from functools import partial
```

the partial function accepts callable function as the first argument and the rest are arguments to be applied to the function

```
partial(str.split, sep='=')
```